# Calculating significance of distribution

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance

I have the following type of data:

```
Age    Type
 3      A
 3      A
 3      A
 4      A
 4      B
 4      A
 5      A
 5      A
 5      B
 6      A
 6      C
 6      B
 7      A
 7      C
 7      B
```

Explanation of the data: essentially, this represents different types of outputs produced by a single child at different ages. For example, at age 3, he can only produce A type output. At age 4 he can start producing B-type output. Once he gets to age 6 he becomes capable of producing C-type output, in addition to the previous two types. The underlying hypothesis is that the child is able to produce C-type output only *after* they have successfully produced B-type output (which must be preceded by A type, though the hypothesis only entails the relationship between C and B).

The measurements reflect the outputs of a single child, measured over a period of several years.

I am trying to show that the distribution of the types (by age) is not due to chance. 
My goal is to show that the fact that type C **first appears** at a later age than type B is not due to chance (i.e. the fact that type B first appears as a result at age 4, while type C first appears at age 6).

What would be the appropriate method to do this?

(I am using R, so any additional input on applying the suggested method there would be appreciated)

Comment: https://www.uvm.edu/~dhowell/StatPages/More_Stuff/OrdinalChisq/OrdinalChiSq.html

Comment: Could you please explain what "first appears" means?  There is no evident way in these data to interpret that phrase.

Comment: @whuber I have edited the post to clarify this. If it still isn't clear, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you.  I think it could help to explain what these data mean.  We need to understand how there might be statistical dependencies among the data and how the data might have varied.  Otherwise there's not enough information to recommend an appropriate procedure.

Comment: Also - are these the same children that you are following over several years, or are these 15 different children?

Comment: @ZahavaKor single child; I have edited the question so that it now contains this information.

Comment: @whuber I added a more in-depth explanation of the data.

Comment: Are you saying the *entire dataset* applies to just one child?  (If so, it is hard to see how any statistical inference to other children could be performed.)  If not, how were the children selected and what population do you want to draw conclusions about?

Comment: @whuber yes, the entire dataset applies to just one child. That's why I'm having difficulty with the analysis. I am trying to show that for that child, the distribution of types (based on age) is not due to chance.

Comment: It's difficult to see how you could do anything besides report the results: what model of chance could apply here?